# Mysql does not error on insert or update to null value on not null field

Tags: mysql, null, innodb, insert-update, notnull

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `devicelist` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `networkname` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(130) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(130) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `peopleid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deviceid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `placeid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stationid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `place` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `placeid` (`placeid`),
  KEY `stationid` (`stationid`),
  KEY `peopleid` (`peopleid`),
  KEY `deviceid` (`deviceid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

as you see the **serial** is set to **NOT NULL**,
but when i run query like

```
UPDATE DeviceList SET serial = NULL WHERE id = 1
```

It outputs

```
1 row affected. ( Query took 0.0079 sec )
```

Why is this inserting null to not null field?
I want an error to occure:D

///****************************** EDIT

well i found the answer
the problem was in sql_mode
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict
my sql_mode was empty by default
iw changed it to STRICT_ALL_TABLES via

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

Answer (score 2):

*MySQL sucked the hell out of my day today because of this so I'm just sharing what I learned about this.*

MySQL 5.6 defaults to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

MySQL 5.7 defaults to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`,  `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`, `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

As stated in this [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) from the MySQL Reference Manual,

> MySQL installation programs may configure the SQL mode during the installation process. For example, **mysql_install_db** creates a default option file named *my.cnf* in the base installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

It should and does throw error. I'd guess the `create table` you posted in the question doesn't correspond actual table definition ( taking into account you have a syntax error - extra comma ).

Comment: well i updated to complete table definition hope this will help to find the problem

Comment: @KoSMoS: double check if you don't have `before update` trigger which may change "serial" on the fly.

Comment: @a1ex07 i did not create any triggers in mysql in my life in :D could there be any default triggers?  in phpmyadmin it says "There are no triggers to display."

Comment: @KoSMoS: One more thing to try : depends on server's OS, table names in mysql can be case-sensitive. So  `DeviceList` and `devicelist` can be 2 different tables. Double check `SHOW CREATE TABLE DeviceList` and see if you have `serial NOT NULL` there...